# Need help parsing the php/html file using python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I would like to perse the url https://www.horsedeathwatch.com/index.php and dump the data into a Pandas data frame.

Column like horse/date/course/cause of death 
I tried  pandas read_html to directly read this url  and it didn't find the table even though it has table tag .

I tried using :

```
  url='https://www.horsedeathwatch.com/index.php'
  #Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
  page = requests.get(url)
  #print(page.text)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
```

and then findall('tr') method but some reason not getting it to work.

Second thing i  would like to do is .. each Horse(first column in the web page table)  has a hyperlink with additional attribute.

any suggestion on how can i retrieve those additional attributes to a pandas data frame

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the site I can see the data is loaded using a POST request to `/loaddata.php` passing the page number. Combining this with pandas.read_html:

```
import requests
import pandas

res = requests.post('https://www.horsedeathwatch.com/loaddata.php', data={'page': '3'})
html = pandas.read_html(res.content)
```

Although perhaps `BeautifulSoup` would give you a richer data structure .. because if you want to extract the further attributes against each horse you would need to get the anchor element's 'href' and perform another request - this one is a GET request and you need to parse the reponse content from `<div class="view">` in the response.